# How to collect all lines of data between keywords in a file - starting+ending at linebreaks

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to collect specific information from very large log files but cannot figure out how to get the behavior I need.

For reference, an example log is sort of like this:

> ```
> garbage I don't need - garbage I don't need
> timestamp - date - server info - 'keyword 1' - data
> more data more data more data more data
> more data more data more data more data
> more data more data 'keyword 2' - last bit of data
> garbage I don't need - garbage I don't need
> ```

What I need is to find 'keyword 1', grab the whole line keyword 1 is on (back to timestamp) and all subsequent lines until (and including) the whole line that 'keyword 2' is on (through the last bit of data).

So far I have tried a few things. I cannot get decent results with re methods (findall, match, search etc.); I cannot figure out how to grab the data before the match (even with a look behind) but more importantly, I cannot figure out how to have the capture stop at a phrase and not just a single character.

```
for match in re.findall('keyword1[keyword2]+|', showall.read()):
```

I also tried something like this:

```
start_capture = False
for current_line in fileName:
    if 'keyword1' in current_line:
        start_capture = True
    if start_capture:
        new_list.append(current_line)
    if 'keyword2' in current_line:
        return(new_list)
```

No matter what I tried, this returned an empty list

Finally,I tried something like this:

```
def takewhile_plus_next(predicate, xs):
for x in xs:
    if not predicate(x):
        break
    yield x
yield x
with lastdb as f:
    lines = map(str.rstrip, f)
    skipped = dropwhile(lambda line: 'Warning: fatal assert' not in line, lines)
    lines_to_keep = takewhile_plus_next(lambda line: 'uptime:' not in line, skipped)
```

This last one took everything from keyword 1 to the EOF which includes almost 100,000 lines of garbage data.

Comment: Look, you tried checking if line contains `keyword1`, but your data has `keyword 1`. Try [this parsing code](https://ideone.com/H06qsD).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that isn't my literal code, in my actual code I have definite matching terms

Comment: So, what is the problem? If these are regexps, use `if re.search(rx, line)` instead of `if 'keyword' in line`.

Comment: First example doesn't initialise `new_list` as a list. Check indentation in the second example.

Comment: @Nick these are just excerpts of the relevant code. In my real code new_list is initialized and remains empty after the block of code runs. the indentation of the second is a matter of text formatting. I didn't realize it got messed up like that on the copy/paste. Again, it is proper in my real code. I appreciate you trying to give feedback though.

Comment: @Toenailsmcgee might you be initialising  `new_list` inside the loop by accident?

Comment: Note that you&#39;re using different keywords in the two examples. Quite encouraging really that you get different results :)

Comment: @Nick the list was initialized outside the loop and it still wasn't populating. also the keywords in the examples are not the real keywords. I figured it out using regex though. Thank you for taking time to help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: `for line in fileName` needs a file handle not a filename. You&#39;re getting empty results because Python will iterate over the characters in the `fileName` string returning single-char strings and none of these can match either keyword. You need `with open(fileName, 'r') as f: ... for line in f:` then the rest of that code looks fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

None of the other responses worked but I was able to figure it out using regex.

```
for match in re.findall(".*keyword1[\s\S]*?keyword2:[\s\S]*?keyword3.*", log_file.read()):
```

Comment: Hey @Toenailsmcgee the above solution is not complete code. That makes it less helpful than it could be.

Comment: My solution works fine for me in Python 2.7 and 3.6, on small and large files, with the extracted lines in initial, final or middle position. If there's a problem with it please let me know what error or what faulty output you're getting. Did you want to find multiple instances of `keyword1` and `keyword2` and extract all? If so, my solution doesn't work-- but that isn't what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex if you specify [`re.dotall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) and use lazy anythings .*? to match start and end:

```
import re

regex = r"\n.*?(keyword 1).*?(keyword 2).*?$"

test_str = ("garbage I don't need - garbage I don't need\n"
    "timestamp - date - server info - 'keyword 1' - data\n"
    "more data more data more data more data\n"
    "more data more data more data more data\n"
    "more data more data 'keyword 2' - last bit of data\n"
    "garbage I don't need - garbage I don't need")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print (match.group()) # your match is the whole group
```

Output:

```
timestamp - date - server info - 'keyword 1' - data 
more data more data more data more data
more data more data more data more data
more data more data 'keyword 2' - last bit of data
```

You might need to `strip('\n')` from it ...

You can view it here: https://regex101.com/r/HWIALZ/1 - it also holds the explanation of the patter. The short of it:

```
\n        newline 
   .*?    as few as possible anythings
   (keyword 1)   literal text - the () are not needed only if you want the group
   .*?    as few as possible anythings
   (keyword 2)   literal text - again () are not needed 
   .*?    as few as possible anythings
$         end of line
```

I included the () for clarity - you do not evaluate groups, you you remove them.

Comment: sorry - I messed up the last edit  -I substituted filename for test_str    matches = re.finditer(regex, filename, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\re.py", line 229, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Toenailsmcgee using `with open(filename,"r") as f: re.finditer(regex,f.read(), .. flags ...)` should do it, unless your files are so big that they don't fit into memory

Comment: @Nick does not work - try it. it would still match but from the start of the first line instead of from the closest \n

Answer (score 1):

The following is fast for any size of file. It extracts from a 250M log file of nearly 2 million lines in 3 seconds. The extracted portion was at the end of the file.

I would not recommend using `list`, regexes or other in-memory techniques if there is a chance your files won't fit in available memory.

Test text file `startstop_text`:

```
line 1 this should not appear in output
line 2 keyword1
line 3 appears in output
line 4 keyword2
line 5 this should not appear in output
```

Code:

```
from itertools import dropwhile


def keepuntil(contains_end_keyword, lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line
        if contains_end_keyword(line):
            break


with open('startstop_text', 'r') as f:
    from_start_line = dropwhile(lambda line: 'keyword1' not in line, f)
    extracted = keepuntil(lambda line: 'keyword2' in line, from_start_line)
    for line in extracted:
        print(line.rstrip())


>>> python startstop.py
line 2 keyword1
line 3 appears in output
line 4 keyword2
```